# Mvc controller on LINQ-to-SQL models

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, datacontext

I am trying to learn linking db with asp.net mvc.

Following the instruction on MS tutorials trying to build a controller.
right click on controller and add a controller, but the data-context pre built by LINQ-to-SQL in VSExpress does not fit, is there any tutorial shows how to build a connection between built db and asp.net mvc web page from zero to pros

[image]

the result after clicking "Add" return Unsupported context type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below Scottgu's  blog link. It may help you.

[linq to sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, a nice tutorial with LINQ-to-SQL, is there any other article that discuss how to due with the mvc controller?

Answer (score 2):

The templates of ASP.Net MVC use *Entity Framework code first* and not *LINQ-to-SQL*. You can either change to use Entity Framework or use new templates (I know somebody who did this but I don't know how).

[Here is an example](http://codesamplez.com/development/net-mvc-with-linq-to-sql-tutorial) that uses Linq-to-SQL with ASP.Net MVC3 but it creates the classes manually, you would still need to create your own templates.